# How to solve javascript not redirecting after google signin?

Tags: javascript, php, google-api, google-signin

I'm trying to implement Google Signin onto my site. How can I redirect users to logged in members page?

I'm now able to verify the token, after the verification, user should be redirected to loggedin members page, I've tried to use javascript to do so, but it seems to be not working.

I've tried manually type the javascript in the console, login is successful.

```
   <?php 
    ...
    require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';
    $client = new Google_Client();
    $client->setScopes('email');
    $payload = $client->verifyIdToken($id_token);
    if ($payload == true) {
       $userid = $payload['sub'];
       //check user existance
       if ($check_googleuser_result->num_rows == 1) {
           $_SESSION['loggedin_userlogin'] = $email;
           //redirect user
           echo '<script>window.location = "loggedin.php";</script>';
        } else {
         echo 'No matched user';
         //signout user
         echo '<script>location.replace("gsignout.php");</script>';
        }
     } else {
         echo 'error';
         //signout user
         echo '<script>location.replace("gsignout.php");</script>';
     }
    ?>
```

Expected to redirect the user after successful check existence of user.

Actual output is that the session is created, but javascript not performing redirection.

UPDATE:[Screenshot of background1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dXYre.png)
[Screenshot of background2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8NXCY.png)

Comment: Simple, don't redirect with JavaScript. Use `header('Location: loggedin.php');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are trying to redirect in your php code, you should also use the php provided functions for that.

For this there is a function called [header()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php)

So your code would look like this:

```
<?php 
    ...
    require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';
    $client = new Google_Client();
    $client->setScopes('email');
    $payload = $client->verifyIdToken($id_token);
    if ($payload == true) {
       $userid = $payload['sub'];
       //check user existance
       if ($check_googleuser_result->num_rows == 1) {
           $_SESSION['loggedin_userlogin'] = $email;
           //redirect user
           header('Location: loggedin.php');
        } else {
         echo 'No matched user';
         //signout user
         header('Location: gsignout.php');
        }
     } else {
         echo 'error';
         //signout user
         header('Location: gsignout.php');
     }
 ?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer and I've just tried it out, it does modify the header, but sadly it is redirecting in background, it doesn't really redirect the user after signin.

Comment: Are you calling this php script through a ajax call?

Comment: Nope, I'm not calling the script with ajax.

Comment: What do you mean with 'it is redirecting him in the background' then?

Comment: I can see the redirection in the network activity when I've opened up the inspector.

Comment: Nobody can help you If you just vaguely state your problem. You need to post the screenshots, error messages, and so on...